# Prestashop help - Language keeps changing back to default

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, default

On my page www.trendee.dk the default language is danish, which is fine, but if you change the language to English, and then go to a new page, it goes back to Danish... How can i make it stay on English?

Also, i've set up different currencies, but when i've clicked on a product and select a different currency, nothing happens, the currency stays the same.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

If your prestashop version is 1.6.0.11 - 1.6.1.0 and maybe later, it can be core bug related with enabled country auto-detect, you can try to do 2 things:

1. Disable in `Localization - Localization` options `Set language from browser` and `Set default country from browser language`.

OR

2. in `classes/controller/FrontController.php` methdd `init()` find line

   `if (validate::isLoadedObject($country) && $this->context->country->id !== $country->id) {`

and add condition `!$has_currency`:

```
if (!$has_currency && validate::isLoadedObject($country) && $this->context->country->id !== $country->id) {
```

Comment: Around what line is it located? 

I have version 1.6.0.14 and both things in Localization are disabled

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a long debugging I solved it. It's a bug introduced in the APS version of Prestashop. As I understand, The APS version is a modified version of Prestashop to work with web server cloud control panels like Plesk. It allows one click installations and other shortcuts. 
Anyway there are two solutions to this problem:

1) The easy one: from the file "settings.inc.php" in the "config" folder, remove or comment out the following line (in my case was line number 20):

```
define('APS', 'ON');
```

2) The longest and more difficult: migrate to the official Prestashop version.  I can imagine that the APS version introduced other bugs, so I think this is the safest solution.

Answer (score 0):

my Prestashop 1.6.1.6 keeps reverting back as USA for the default country, keeps disabling my second language and also keeps reverting back to default settings for other features which causes my clients to be unable to view products or place orders. Is there any way to stop it from doing that?

Comment: I am not anative speaker of english language, but is **this** an answer to that 8 month old question. It looks like a question itself, with no code in it but the word product. I doubt this is the right place ... please edit accordingly or move the txt where it belongs. Thanks.